# Android print preview disable

Tags: mobile, printing

I have an issue where I want the document to print immediately when I click 'Print,' without needing a preview.

I'm facing a specific problem with my printing process. When I click the 'Print' button, I would like the document to be sent directly to the printer without generating a preview. In other words, I want it to start printing immediately without any intermediate steps or previews.